# Getting error when I try to use GraphicsMagick in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, thumbnails, graphicsmagick

I am using graphicsMagick in my node code.

```
   var tokenvalue;
   tokenvalue = randomstring.generate({
       length: 16,
       numeric: true,
       letters: true,
       special: false,
    });
    var image = tokenvalue + '.png';
    var pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, req.file.path)
    , pathToSnapshot =path.join(__dirname,pro_root_path+'public/uploads/thumbnail/'+image);
        gm(pathToFile).thumb(150, // Width
                    150, // Height
             pathToSnapshot, // Output file name
             40, // Quality from 0 to 100
             function (error, stdout, stderr, command) {
                   if (!error) {
                   console.log("command");
                   }
                   else {
                   console.log(error);
                   }
                  });
```

Am getting error like this :

```
Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "identify" "-ping" "-format" "%wx%h" "E:\vishnu\Thumbnail View for doc\folder\app\public\uploads\docs\tmp\mypdf.pdf" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\vishnu\Thumbnail View for doc\folder\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:232:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (E:\vishnu\Thumbnail View for doc\folder\node_modules\gm\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:36:37)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

I have done search and install graphics magic for windows. But even though am getting error. What I have to do. I need to convert pdf to thumbnail(in any format jpeg,png,gif) Is there any other npm to sort out this issue.

Comment: Open the command prompt and type `gm`, then hit enter. Does the program run? Or are you getting a "command not found" type message? If the latter, fix that first (i.e. add to your Windows PATH environment variable)

Comment: Its showing the versions... Inside c: and E: as well But its showing not found inside my node project